# localhost phpMyAdmin does not display correct database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I downloaded Xampp and followed directions I found online to set it up on my Windows computer (localhost).  I installed WordPress and began building 2 websites.

I'm now trying to migrate one of the websites to my remote host servers (SiteGround) but I'm having difficulty finding, copying and uploading the correct localhost database.

The main problem is that the database containing the work I completed is not showing up in the localhost phpMyAdmin list, which I am trying to use to save the database tables as an SQL file.

When I first created the database I made a mistake after creating a DB titled "fs". When I redid the installation, I named the new database "wp-2".  The mostly empty "fs" DB is displayed in the phpMyAdmin list (on the left), but "wp-2" is not.  There are other DBs listed as well, but not the one I need.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this, or some other way to find and save the correct DB?

I'm also having trouble finding it in the local directory.  I think it should be in xampp/mysql/data, but that directory only contains the "fs" DB as well.

I am able to access and display the WordPress website using localhost/wp-2/wordpress, but I cannot find the associated DB.

I've spent 2 days now trying to find a solution, but I'm stuck.  Please help.

Thank you!

Comment: Find your wp-config.php and see where it's pointed to. Maybe it's not where you expect it to be

Comment: When looking at phpMyAdmin click on the little house (home) icon in the left panel. In the right panel you should see a bunch of tabs and one of them should be titled databases. If you see that tab and click on it are all of your databases shown?

Comment: The wp-config file in the wp-2 > wordpress directory shows ('DB_NAME', 'fs');

Comment: The databases tab shows 8 DBs: fs, information_schema, mtfm (another website), mysql, performance_schema, phpmyadmin, test, wp.

Comment: If the config in the wp-2 folder is pointed to 'fs' then maybe I'm not saving it in phpMyAdmin correctly.  When I click "Export", template fields come up and that's where I'm trying to do it.

Comment: I'm wondering if you're database became corrupt. If you were running on linux you could have checked it via command line.

Comment: Is there a way to check that?

Comment: Would running without adminstraor rights affect this?

Comment: I'm a bit embarrased to ask this question, but how do I enable administrator rights for Xampp?